# Laravel Ajax dropdown example

Tags: ajax, laravel

can someone please share working example of laravel ajax dropdown. there are so many examples about dependable dropdown, but i want simple dropdown of only one column, i have two tables teacher and nation, when teacher profile is open i want dropdown of nationality using ajax.
i have done it without ajax, but i don't know how to do with ajax.
**without ajax:**

```
<select name="nation_id" class="custom-select" >
    <option selected value=" ">Choose...</option>
    @foreach($nations as $nations)
    <option value="{{@$nation_id}}"  {{@$teacher->nation_id== $nations->id ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{@$nations->nation}}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Controller:**

```
$nations = nation::all();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel dynamic dropdown country and state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060108/laravel-dynamic-dropdown-country-and-state)

Comment: i need simple one column dropdown. above shares answer is about two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" name="nation_id" id="nation_id">
          <option value="">Select nation</option>
           @foreach($nations as $nation) 
            <option value="{{ $nation->nation_id }}">{{ $nation->nation_name }}  </option>
          @endforeach
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="teacher" id="teacher">
</select>
```

now the ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#nation_id).change(function(){
    var nid = $(this).val();
    if(nid){
        $.ajax({
           type:"get",
           url:"{{url('/getTeacher)}}/"+nid,
           success:function(res)
           {       
                if(res)
                {
                    $("#teacher").empty();
                    $("#state").append('<option>Select Teacher</option>');
                    $.each(res,function(key,value){
                        $("#teacher").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    });
                }
           }

        });
        }
});
</script>
```

now in controller file;

```
public function getTeacher($id)
{
    $states = DB::table("teachers")
                ->where("nation_id",$id)
                ->pluck("teacher_name","teacher_id");
    return response()->json($teachers);    
}
```

And last for route file:

```
Route::get('/getTeacher/{id}','TeachersController@getTeacher');
```

Hope this will work..
Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

Create a route for your method which will fetch all the nations-

```
Route::get('nations-list', 'YourController@method');
```

Create a method in your controller for the above route-

```
public function method()
{
    $nations = Nation::all()->pluck('nation', 'id');

    return response()->json($nations)
}
```

Add a select box like this in your HTML-

```
<select id="nation_id" name="nation_id"></select>
```

If you want to auto select the option based on a variable then you can do this-

```
<input type="hidden" name="teacher_nation_id" id="teacher_nation_id" value="{{ $teacher->nation_id ?? '' }}">
```

And then add this script in your HTML to fetch the nation list on page load-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.get('nations-list', function(data) {
        let teacher_nation_id = $('#teacher_nation_id').val();
        let nations = $('#nation_id');
        nations.empty();

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            nations.append("<option value='"+ key +"'>" + value + "</option>");
        });

        nations.val(teacher_nation_id); // This will select the default value
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i tried your code it shows empty dropdown, can you please check.