# Dependency dropdown from database in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-7

I have two select fields (City, Area). The city field's data will automatically show from the database. But Area data will be shown depends on the City from the database. No one can select the Area without selecting the City. There is `(id, city_id, area_name)` column in the Area table.

Please have a look at my code:

```
<select name="city" id="city">
            <option value="">City</option>
            @foreach($citylist as $city)
                <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->city_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <select name="area" id="area">
            <option value="">Area</option>
            @foreach($arealist as $area)
                <option value="{{$area->id}}">{{$area->area_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

How can I do that in Laravel 7?

Comment: Use AJAX for this job.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of ajax. Can you share something so that I can learn?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017659/laravel-ajax-dropdown-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a blog which is kind of similar to this problem,
Kindly go through [this blog](https://developersdesk.home.blog/2019/03/08/laravel-country-state-city-dropdown-with-ajax/)

Hope this will help!
Good luck