# Get Child Table Values linked to Specific Parent Table Value (dependent dropdown)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my Blade file, there are two dropdowns, "Countries" and "Regions".  I want the Regions dropdown only to display the values linked to the country selected in the "Countries" dropdown.

For that, I believe, I have to pass a variable for `$countries` and `$regions` in order to compact them and call the variables in the blade file.

This is what I currently have (which is totally  wrong), but what should it be?

```
    public function create()
    {
        $countries = Countries::orderBy('name')->get();
        $regions = Regions::where('countries_id' == $countries('id'))->orderBy('name')->get();
        return view('admin.cities.create', compact('regions', 'countries'));
    }
```

I know that the `$regions` variable part "`where('countries_id' == $countries('id'))`" is incorrect, but I've tried multiple other ways, and still not able to figure it out.

Is this `variable = model::where(foreign_key == parent_table ID)` possible?

All my relationships have been set up with Laravel Eloquent already.

Comment: You should not do this in your controller. In order to do that, you should change the regions in your blade file with javascript by selected country.

Answer (score 1):

I started to write how to fetch data from controller(Country::all and Regions::all), and what to do in blade file and ajax functions that does stuff on events and figured - maybe there already is a solution.

Keep in mind you need the  part in the bottom of the page!

[Laravel dynamic dropdown country and state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060108/laravel-dynamic-dropdown-country-and-state)